# Runtime complexity of preorder full binary tree

Tags: python, c++, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-tree

```
void preorder(Node *root)
{
    if (!root)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        temp += root->data;
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);
}
```

What would be the time complexity if I have a for loop for doing some processing in a recursive function?

Comment: How many times is each node visited?

Comment: Its a preorder traversal so all nodes are just visited once.

Comment: Since all nodes are visited once, you almost answered your own question, isn't it? It is `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the tree. Did I missed something?

Comment: Well I was wondering if the for loop contributes to the time complexity.

Comment: Yes it does but the loop is bounded by a constant value so the complexity has a constant factor too which can be removed (constant factor does not matters in complexity although it is good to consider them when they are huge)

Comment: What if instead of a constant value such as 100 I have "k" which increments every time a call to the recursive function is performed?

Comment: I think the complexity in time should be quadratic in that case if I understand your example correctly. Can you show a short precise example code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241961/discussion-between-sharath-chander-p-and-jerome-richard).

Comment: What is the purpose of `temp`?

Comment: temp is just a variable to show that I have a statement inside the for-loop (you can also have a simple print statement. It won't matter). My concern is with the run time alone.

Comment: What about the comment above where you say 100 is replaced with `k`? Is it `k` or is 100? Is `k` an argument to the function or is it a constant?

Comment: @trincot See the above discussion in the chat.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I saw it, but the question needs to have all the information to be able to answer it.